# Entity Framework 4.3 database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4.3

I have some problems with EF code-first.

I have 4 projects in one solution

1. Data Access Layer
2. Logic
3. MobileUi
4. Security

and then I use MVC code-first in part 4 (Security)

My problem issue when I want use my methods in `MobileUI` from my methods in `Security` part, this is the error when it want use `UserBlackList` table

> *The entity type UserBlackList is not part of the model for the current
>   context.*

Comment: In which project do you have your `DbContext`?

Comment: My DbContext in MVC Project(Security)

Comment: DbContext should be in Data Access Layer.

Comment: u mean all class and db context should be in data layer ??